# high 'total_worker_time' for stored proc using OPENQUERY in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, openquery

*[Cross posted from the Database Administrators site, in the hope that it may gain better traction here. I'll update either site as appropriate.]*

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 (SP2) which contains a single query like the following (simplified for clarity)

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYODBC, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Option = ''Y'' ')
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

When this proc is run (and run only once) I can see the plan appear in sys.dm_exec_query_stats with a high 'total_worker_time' value (eg. 34762.196 ms). This is close to the elapsed time. However, in SQL Management Studio the statistics show a much lower CPU time, as I'd expect (eg. 6828 ms). The query takes some time to return, because of the slowness of the server it is talking to, but it doesn't return many rows.

I'm aware of the issue that parallel queries in SQL Server 2005 can present odd CPU times, which is why I've tried to turn off any parallism with the query hint (though I really don't think that there was any in any case).

I don't know how to account for the fact that the two ways of looking at CPU usage can differ, nor which of the two might be accurate (I have other reasons for thinking that the CPU usage may be the higher number, but it's tricky to measure). Can anyone give me a steer?

**UPDATE**: I was assuming that the problem was with the OPENQUERY so I tried looking at times for a long-running query which doesn't use OPENQUERY. In this case the statistics (gained by setting STATISTICS TIME ON) reported the CPU time at 3315ms, whereas the DMV gave it at 0.511ms. The total elapsed times in each case agreed.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible test case so we can see if we get the same results?

Comment: I have tried to produce a test rig, but the only way that I can get a genuine difference in cpu time and elapsed time is to run the stored proc against a busy system. Putting in artificial waits doesn't help. So I'm struggling to see how I can make a test rig with this property (or at least, one that's simple enough to post here).

Answer (score 0):

`total_worker_time` in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` is cumulative - it is the total execution time for all the executions of the currently compiled version of the query - see `execution_count` for the number of executions this represents.

See `last_worker_time`, `min_worker_time` or `max_worker_time` for timing of individual executions.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

Comment: Yes, thankyou, I should have made it clear in the question that I was looking at the statistics for a single execution only. It may be that I'm missing something obvious, but this isn't the obvious thing that I'm missing.